# Local Website Being Redirecting to Live

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, localhost

I have been developing with visual studio for years and this issue just started occurring. So a minor explanation, I have a website which is live and periodically I add changes to it (pretty normal).

So I open visual studio, do the necessary changes and hit F5 to run it and see the changes locally. The problem is that for a few seconds when chrome opens, you can see the address being `"localhost:50792/"` but then it immediately gets translated to its published website which is live. So from `"localhost:50792"` automatically its converted to "`http://www.<websitenamehere>.com"`

I tried changing the project URL of iis express, I cleared the browser cache, tried it on Firefox and internet explorer but the localhost URL always gets changed automatically to its live address.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

I would appreciate any help as I am lost.

Comment: Search for the term "redirect", or the HTTP codes 301 or 302 in your project and tell us what you find. There might also be information of interest in the `<rewrite>` section of your `web.config` (if it exists).

Comment: Also, use your browser's dev tools to see what network requests are happening. You might need to turn on "persist" or "preserve log" in the network panel to see the full story.

Comment: Check your website properties, if it has something related to this.

Comment: Did you get anywhere?

Comment: Yes Spender you were right. Had some code in the web.config which I totally forgot about. Thanks